# Translation into Latin

Tags: english, latin

I would like to translate the following phrase into Latin.

```
Unto the Lion and the Lamb
```

Please provide a translation into English.

Using Google Translate I got the following:

```
In Leo et Agnus
```

but I'm not sure that it means what I want. When I translate the Latin into English I get

```
The Lion and the Lamb.
```

Thanks.

PK

Comment: "Unto" has too many meanings to be translated unambiguously. Speak unto them? Fall unto them? Cast spell unto them?

Comment: I mean 'unto' as in 'it was given unto him'. Is that any clearer?

Comment: Then 'unto' is not translated. It will be "Leōnī et Agnō" or "Leōnī Agnōque" which is the same.

Comment: Hey Yellow Sky, convert your response to an answer and get a thumbs up! ;-)

Comment: This site is not a translation question. This is off-topic and will be closed.

Comment: Google translate is useless, especially for Latin and all highly inflected languages. The correct answer to your question was given by @YellowSky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Leōnī et Agnō" or "Leōnī Agnōque" which is the same.